# OOP access to html5 video variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oop

I can't access currentSrc variable of html5 video when in OOP.

```
if (typeof vidPlayer === "undefined") {
var vidPlayer = {};
}
vidPlayer.videoObj = $('video');
vidPlayer.videos_list = [{
        'id': 0,
        'name': '01_Main_entrance.mp4'
    }, {
        'id': 1,
        'name': '03_Meeting_of_zones.mp4'
    }, {
        'id': 2,
        'name': '04_Goods_entrance.mp4'
    }, {
        'id': 3,
        'name': '05_Tissue_cultures.mp4'
}];

vidPlayer.changeVideo = function(selector) {
    console.log(this.videoObj);
    console.log(this.videos_list);
    var url = vidPlayer.videoObj[0].currentSrc;
    var url_arr = url.split('/');
    var file_name = url_arr[url_arr.length - 1];

    for (var i = 0; i < vidPlayer.video_list.length; ++i) {
        if (vidPlayer.video_list[i].name == file_name) {
            if ($(selector).attr('class') == 'next') {
                var id = carousel(vidPlayer.video_list[i].id,vidPlayer.video_list.length - 1,'+');
                var source = 'videos/' + vidPlayer.video_list[id].name;
                loadVideo(source);
            }
            if ($(selector).attr('class') == 'prev') {
                var id = carousel(vidPlayer.video_list[i].id,vidPlayer.video_list.length - 1,'-');
                if (vidPlayer.video_list[i].id == 0) {
                    var id = vidPlayer.video_list.length - 1;
                } else {
                    var id = vidPlayer.video_list[i].id - 1;
                }
                var source = 'videos/' + vidPlayer.video_list[id].name;
                loadVideo(source);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

So Ican't access property currentSrc and I am getting : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentSrc' of undefined.

Comment: I added some more code.

Comment: It's working fine now after initiate object in document ready function thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably is that you define your `vidPlayer` object with all its properties before it is loaded into your structure. This is due to the fact that your `script` is included before the relevant part of your html. You need to define your event inside the document ready event, or even in a later running event, depending on how do you generate your html. Basically you have to make sure you are calling `$('video')` when it is already present in your html.